# What is the org-mode equivalent of \gls{keyword} in LaTeX?

Tags: org-mode, writing

Is there an org-mode equivalent of the LaTeX glossary package?

Use case - you have an external file with a glossary list, the \gls{keyword} gets expanded at compile time to whatever is referenced in the external file.

Comment: `{{{MACRO}}}` ?

Comment: You can put literal LaTeX into your Org mode file: it will be added as-is to the exported `.tex` file. If you are looking for something that will work with multiple export formats, I don't think one exists.

Comment: @mankoff - thanks I'll have a look at Macro - I was hoping for something more organised specifically for glossary management - but macro might work.

Comment: @OrgAddict is `{{{GLS(keyword)}}}` better? :).

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to look at [John Kitchin's org-ref](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref), which also includes [glossary support](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/blob/master/org-ref-glossary.el).